# How do I refer to a variable while assigning a value to it, whilst retaining immutability?

Tags: scala, immutability

I'm fiddling around on my Sunday afternoon and am trying to create a 'room' structure of sorts. Basically, a `Room` object has a number of exits, which each refer to other `Room`s. Now, the first thing I'm trying to create is two `Room`s connected to each other, preferably in a single assignment statement. Like this:

```
case class Room(title: String, exits: Map[Direction.Direction, Room])

val firstRoom = Room("A room", Map(North -> Room("Another room", Map(South -> firstRoom))))
```

Ergo: Room one has an exit `North` to room two, room two has an exit `South` back to room one.

However, as you can imagine, this goes wrong: the `firstRoom` val is not defined while creating it, so trying to refer to it during its assignment won't work.

I'm pretty sure this is true for most, if not all programming languages. My question: How do I solve this *without* making my `Room` object mutable? I can simply create a few `Room` objects and add the exits to them afterwards, but that makes the `Room`s mutable, and as a personal exercise I try to avoid that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Non-Recursive**

I think your best option is to do something like this

```
object Rooms {
  case class Room(title: String) {
    def exits = exitMap(this)
  }
  val first:Room = Room("first")
  val second:Room = Room("second")

  private val exitMap = Map(first -> Map("S" -> second), second -> Map("N" -> first))
}

scala> Rooms.first.title
res: String = first

scala> Rooms.first.exits
res: scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,Rooms.Room] = Map(S -> Room(second))
```

It is perfectly immutable and you avoid nasty recursions.

**Recursive**

Constructing a recursive structure takes much more care as Scala is not lazy by default. Specifically, it is not possible to create a lazy or call-by-name `case class` parameter. So, we’ll have to resort to a specialised data structure for this.

One option could be to use `Stream`s:

```
case class LazyRoom(title: String, exits: Stream[LazyRoom])

object LazyRooms {
  lazy val nullRoom: LazyRoom = LazyRoom("nullRoom", Stream.empty)
  lazy val first: LazyRoom = LazyRoom("first", nullRoom #:: second #:: Stream.empty)
  lazy val second: LazyRoom = LazyRoom("second", nullRoom #:: first #:: Stream.empty)
}

scala> LazyRooms.first.exits(1).title
res> String: second
```

To be on the save side, I prefixed a dummy room before each `Stream` to avoid premature access. (A Stream is only lazy in its tail but not in its head.) A dedicated data structure might be able to avoid this.

**Cleaned up version**

We can do better with a call-by-name helper function to do the dirty work:

```
case class LazyRoom(title: String, exitMap: Stream[Map[String, LazyRoom]]) {
  def exits = exitMap(1) // skip the Streams empty head
}

def _exitMap(mappedItems: => Map[String, LazyRoom]) = {
  Map[String, LazyRoom]() #::
  mappedItems #::
  Stream.empty
}

object LazyRooms {
  lazy val first: LazyRoom = LazyRoom("first", _exitMap(Map("South" -> second)))
  lazy val second: LazyRoom = LazyRoom("second", _exitMap(Map("North" -> first)))
}

scala> LazyRooms.first.exits
res: Map[String,LazyRoom] = Map(South -> LazyRoom(second,Stream(Map(), ?)))
```

Comment: Epic answer, you deserve all the upvotes you can get. Not only do you provide a simple answer, but also a deeper one about a language feature I hadn't had a chance to use yet or found a purpose for. I came across streams once or twice when searching for this answer, but hadn't a clue how they would solve this. Much obliged.

Answer (score 2):

I totally agree with Debilski's answer, but I couldn't resist replacing the method `exists` with a lazy val `exists`, preventing the lookup from happening over and over again.

```
object Rooms {
  case class Room(title: String) {
    lazy val exits = exitMap(this)
  }
  val first:Room = Room("first")
  val second:Room = Room("second")

  private val exitMap = Map(first -> Map("S" -> second), second -> Map("N" -> first))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution, which unfortunately (I think) doesn't work with case classes:

```
class Room(val title: String, _exits : => Map[String, Room]) { lazy val exits = _exits }
val room1 : Room = new Room("A room", Map("N" -> room2))
val room2 : Room = new Room("Another room", Map("S" -> room1))
```

Another option would be to use a "lazy" map:

```
case class Room(val title : String, exits : Map[String, () => Room])
val room1 : Room = Room("A room", Map("N" -> (() => room2)))
val room2 : Room = Room("Another room", Map("S" -> (() => room1)))
```

The syntax would be nicer if you made your own lazy map implementation extending the scala.collection.immutable.Map trait.